# Volley success and error code handle

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

I am basically new to volley but unlike apache http old libraries I used to do like this to handle response along with status code to show aler dialog regarding success and failed response:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String mre = null;

            stringEntity=new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


            httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


            switch (statusCode){
                case 200:
                    entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    System.out.println("Entity post is: "
                            + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                    mre = "200";
                    Log.d("SUCCESS","YES FINALLY");
                    Log.d("Ok",entity.toString());

                    break;
                case 412:
                    mre = "412";
                    Log.d("412", "412 WE MEET AGAIN)");
                    break;
                default:
                    mre="unknown";
                    Log.i("Unknown","Unknown Server Error");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mre;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String mre) {
        super.onPostExecute(mre);
        hideDialog();

        if(mre.equalsIgnoreCase("200")){

         //HANDLE HERE
        }
        else if(mre.equalsIgnoreCase("412")){


            //HANDLE HERE

        }
        else
        if(mre.equalsIgnoreCase("unknown")){

            //HANDLE HERE


        }
```

But in volley I am confused, I need to handle every status code received from server so that I can show user a message.(SUCCESS/FAILED )

A bit help would deeply appreciated